# UIControl to create a popup in an ios ipad application

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I want to create a popup window (like given in image) in an ipad application. What UI Control that i should be using. It would be great if someone can suggest me a tutorial. I am looking for ipad only application.

[image: Popup window in ipad]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is view controller presented in modal mode. See - [presentModalViewController:animated:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentModalViewController%3aanimated%3a)

[View Controller Programming Guide for iOS - Presentation Styles for Modal Views](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW15)